# how to showing time elapsed in a media element in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

how can i showing time elapsed of a video file who is playing in a MediaElement control in silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i resolve my problem with this way:
i use a Textblock control and bind text property to Position property of MediaElement control, then i use a IvalueConverter to show appropriate Time in TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock MinWidth="40" Text="{Binding ElementName=myMediaElement, Path=Position, Converter={StaticResource TimeConverterFormatter}}"/>
```

TimeConverterFormatter is a class for convert TimeSpan value to short time format. because position property in MediaElement show a Timespan value like to "0:00:00:00.0000000" and i want elapsed time value like to this: "00:00"

```
public class TimeConverterFormatter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString().Length == 16)
            return value.ToString().Substring(3, 2) + ":" + value.ToString().Substring(6, 2);

        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `Position` property on the `MediaElement`.  This video and source code should help you out http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/audioandvideo/

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is an old question now, but in WPF you can just use a normal `StringFormat` to do what you want:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Position, ElementName=myMediaElement, 
    StringFormat={}{0:hh}:{0:mm}, FallbackValue=00:00, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

I couldn't work out whether you wanted hours and minutes or minutes and seconds, so here is the latter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Position, ElementName=myMediaElement, 
    StringFormat={}{0:mm}:{0:ss}, FallbackValue=00:00, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

I can't guarantee that it will work in Silverlight though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Silverlight but this should work to show mm:ss.

```
lblLength.Content = String.Format("{0:mm}:{0:ss}", mediaElement.Position);
```